# Prometheus: Add custom labels to metrics out of box

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator, prometheus-alertmanager

We have deployed prometheus operator along with other components like node-exporter, blackbox-exporter on multiple k8s cluster. Now we have one Grafana and AlertManager.

**Distributed**: Prometheus, Node-exporter, Blackbox-exporter etc

**Centralized**: Grafana, AlertManager

Now on all k8s cluster, there are some services running with SAME name and namespace.
Is there any way inject custom labels like cluster or identifier to distinguish metrics among cluster.

Googled alot and found `externalLabels: {}` which can do needful for us but there is one catch that **this label with attach only while communicating with external systems.** Not sure, is there any option available to achieve the same specially with my architecture.

**Note: We are not using Thanos.**

[image]

Comment: IIUC, see [relabel_configs vs metric_relabel_configs](https://www.robustperception.io/relabel_configs-vs-metric_relabel_configs/) and the post's links for examples of target filtering|relabeling.